# PyQt4 does not redirect me to the next page

Tags: python, hyperlink, click, pyqt, qwebkit

The code below works fine except one thing, it does not follow the sign-up link.
However if I go to my actual browser and in console type:

```
document.getElementById("link-signup").click()
```

It will redirect me to the desired page. I was thinking that the problem accured because I didn't enable some feature in settings. but I'm not sure.

Thank's for any help

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys

class GrabberSettings(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)

class Grabber(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.setPage(GrabberSettings())
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadComplete)
        self.doc = self.page().mainFrame().documentElement()

    def _loadComplete(self):
        print "Done"
        link = self.doc.findFirst('a[link-signup]')
        if link:
            print "link found"
        link.evaluateJavaScript('click()')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Grabber()
    gmail = QUrl('https://accounts.google.com')
    view.load(gmail)
    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `click()` failure may have something to do with how the google page uses javascript to transform the original `A` element after it loads. If you wrap your `evaluateJavaScript()` call in an `alert()`, you can see that the `click` method is `null`

```
link.evaluateJavaScript('this.click')
```

It is not a 100% cross-browser support to be able to call "click" on a link. It would need to be a button.

You have a couple alternatives...

**(#1) Just navigate to the href of the link**

```
def _loadComplete(self):
    page = self.page()
    doc = page.currentFrame().documentElement()
    link = doc.findFirst('#link-signup')
    if link and not link.isNull():
        self.load(QUrl.fromEncoded(link.attribute('href').toAscii()))
```

**(#2) Simulate a click on the web view**

```
def _loadComplete(self):
    page = self.page()
    doc = page.currentFrame().documentElement()
    link = doc.findFirst('#link-signup')
    if link and not link.isNull():
        pos = link.geometry().center()
        self._doMouseClick(page, pos)
    else:
        print "Link not found"

@staticmethod
def _doMouseClick(obj, pos):
    # mouse down
    evt = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonPress, pos, 
                            Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
    QApplication.sendEvent(obj, evt)
    # mouse up
    evt = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease, pos, 
                            Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
    QApplication.sendEvent(obj, evt)
```

**(#3) Make the link clickable via javascript**

```
def _loadComplete(self):
    page = self.page()
    doc = page.currentFrame().documentElement()
    link = doc.findFirst('#link-signup')
    if link and not link.isNull():
        link.evaluateJavaScript("""
            var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            e.initEvent('click', true, true);
            this.dispatchEvent(e);  
        """)
```