# PyQT Wizard buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, wizard

I have created a Qwizard in PyQT with 5 pages. I can not figure out how to connect signals to them. How it's works to connect to a next button of a certain page?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553817/pyqt4-does-not-redirect-me-to-the-next-page

Comment: or see this blog it's better http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/webkit-pyqt-rendering-web-pages/

Comment: Is the webkit equivalent to the wizard?

Comment: they all have the same code behind them

Answer (score 2):

If you add the wizard with

```
QWizard.AddPage(somePage)
```

**The order in which pages are inserted, is also the order in which they will be shown**, by pressing the "next" button; you should not need to do anything to set a sequence among pages.

This is because the wizard is initializing default sequential IDs. 
If you want to change the default behaviour (let's say call page 3 from page 1), you may do so by reimplementing this function:

```
    def nextId(self):
```

In the class reference, you have an example of the implementation of a non-linear wizard, where they reimplement the nextId():

http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qwizard.html

Answer (score 1):

you can connect the button clicked signal in this way:

```
 ....
 def __init__(self):
    self.button(QWizard.NextButton).clicked.connect(self.test)
 def test(self):
    id = self.currentId()
    ....
```